# HTML/PHP Delete field from database-connected table

Tags: php, html

Trying to add a delete button field on the right side of my table. This is my table in **main.php**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo
              "<tr>
              <td>{$row['id']}</td>
              <td>{$row['one']}</td>
              <td>{$row['two']}</td>
              <td>{$row['three']}</td>
              <td><a href='/delete.php?id=<?php echo {$row['id']}; ?>'>Delete</a></td><?php
              </tr>\n";
              
          }
          /*freeresultset*/
          $result->free();
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**delete.php**:

```
<?php

include "dbConn.php"; // Using database connection file here

$id = $_GET['id']; // get id through query string

$del = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM number_table WHERE id = '$id'"); // delete query

if($del)
{
    mysqli_close($db); // Close connection
    header("location:main.php"); // redirects to all records page
    exit;   
}
else
{
    echo "Error deleting record"; // display error message if not delete
}
?>
```

My database has the following columns: id(primary key), one, two, three.
The delete button should up, without any error, when I press it, it redirects to main.php, but the row doesn't get deleted. Do any of you have any suggestions why that is?

Comment: the `main.php` and `delete.php` are in same folder???

Comment: the data is showing in table with delete link???

Comment: @KUMAR Yes, they are both in public_html. And yes, all the data is showing correctly with delete link on each row.

Comment: You already are in PHP when `echo`ing your "button", no need to escape to PHP again using `<?php echo {$row['id']}; ?>`. Inspect your element in your browser to see if there is an `id` attached to your link. Plus `<?php  </tr>\n";` makes no sense too

Comment: if both files are in same folder than remove \ before delete.php  from <a href='/delete.php?id=<?php echo {$row['id']}; ?>'>Delete</a>

Comment: @KUMAR Just tried this, but it still doesn't remove the row from my table.

Comment: @kerbh0lz Cleaned up my code now, but still not working.

Comment: can you get your `id` in `$id = $_GET['id'];`

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by changing this line from:

```
<td><a href='/delete.php?id=<?php echo {$row['id']}; ?>'>Delete</a></td><?php
```

to

```
<td><a href='delete.php?id={$row['id']};'>Delete</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have had a similar issue, please see what i have done below,

First i declared my a $id and use this for the delete

```
<?php
      if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $id = $row['id']; //added variable here 
               echo
              "<tr>
              <td>{$row['id']}</td>
              <td>{$row['one']}</td>
              <td>{$row['two']}</td>
              <td>{$row['three']}</td>
              <td><a href='/delete.php?id=$id'>Delete</a></td><?php  //changed link to $id
              </tr>\n";
              
          }
          /*freeresultset*/
          $result->free();
      }
    ?>
```

this is what worked for me.
Also you should check if your records are deleting and you are just not getting an error because your redirect does not exits in the folder you are in.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to again call the php for $row['id']. You already in php.

main.php

```
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>One</th>
          <th>Two</th>
          <th>Three</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
        include "dbConn.php";
        $query = "SELECT id, name FROM number_table";
          if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  echo
                  "<tr>
                    <td>{$row['id']}</td>
                      <td>{$row['one']}</td>
                      <td>{$row['two']}</td>
                      <td>{$row['three']}</td>
                    <td><a href='/delete.php?id={$row['id']}'>Delete</a></td>
                  </tr>";
              }
              /*freeresultset*/
              $result->free();
          }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
    include "dbConn.php"; // Using database connection file here

    $id = $_GET['id']; // get id through query string

    include "dbConn.php"; // Using database connection file here
    $sql = "DELETE FROM number_table WHERE id=$id";

    if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      header("location:/test/index.php"); // redirects to all records page
        exit;
    } else {
      echo "Error deleting record: " . $mysqli->error;
    }
?>
```